# Getting local host name

Tags: java, host

When I try to get the hostname of my machine from the code, I'm using the following:

```
address = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName();
```

The above throws an excpetion (UnknownHostException) if the host is composed of dots (for example "My.Host") or _.

I still am interested in the above host names. Is there any other option to fetch them?

Answer (score 0):

You may better try to use this:

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()
```

`getCanonicalHostName()` will do a reverse DNS lookup, whereas `getHostName()` would return the stored hostname.

Also check  [getHostName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostAddress%28%29)

> Returns the IP address string in textual presentation.